# Navbar mobile display bugs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm brand new to developing with Angular/Bootstrap, and am currently developing a website for a Charity;

While my Navbar works perfect on a large (laptop/PC) display, when viewing thru a mobile (small screen) any menu item you hover over becomes transparent.

I know its obviously a CSS property, and im assuming its the hover property, but im not sure how to express it in my custom CSS.

Here's a screen capture to show what i mean[image]

I'm using the following CSS code to help format my Navbar..

```
.navbar-xs { min-height:65px; height: 65px; background-color: #ffffff; border: 0;}
.navbar-xs .navbar-brand{ padding: 0px 12px;font-size: 20px;line-height: 35px; background-color: #ffffff;}
.navbar-xs .navbar-nav > li > a {  padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 5px; line-height: 28px; color: #000fb5; background-color: #ffffff; }
body {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
```

And here's a small sample of the HTML for the navbar (its a large menu, so i only included a sample)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-xs navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
              <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a href="#/" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
         </div>
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

             <!-- Home Menu -->
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Home </b><span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                 <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                   <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#who">Who We Are</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#what">What We Do</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#why">Why We Do It</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#history">Our History</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                 <li><a href="#news">Latest News</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#events">Coming Events</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#calendar">Calendar</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#ceo">CEO Message</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#bibleRead">Bible Reading</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#pray">Pray For Us</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
```

Otherwise, the website can presently be viewed here;
[Current Website](http://bliss.net.au/OpenHouse)

Otherwise, my source can be viewed on my GitHub here;
[GitHub source](https://github.com/BlissMediaSolutions/OpenHouse)

And if anyone has any suggestions as to how else improve the site, I welcome feedback - as the charity wont provide me with any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add bgcolor to your dropdown nav

add below code this should work

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: #e7e7e7!important;
  }
  .container>.navbar-collapse {
        background-color: #fff!important;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Re my response above - I tired your suggestion but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You add css in file this code addd

```
.navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
 overflow: visible;
 }
```

Comment: That didn't work either...
Again using the Inspect function within Chrome, if i have the following it will work;
`.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
}`
but i just still can't get it to override the CSS settings from navbar.css